# RasDial not using IP?

Tags: network-programming, c++-cli, ras

I'm using RasDial (in managed C++) to dial out a VPN connection. The connection doesn't go through, and I was looking at the GUI interface in Windows's connections list. When I look at properties\networking to see the list of components (aka, where you go to set an IP address), I see that neither "Internet Protocol Version 4" or "Internet Protocol Version 6" are checked. What does it even mean for RAS to be trying to connect without IP? How do I make RAS use IPv4?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On the RASENTRY you create to setup the phonebook, set dwfNetProtocols=RASNP_Ip. (in case you want IPv6, just set it =RASNP_Ipv6; of course I only finally figure it out after asking for help)